# ¿Cambiar una imagen con JS despues de haber sido cargada con angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

Estoy intentando hacer un "snippet" de chrome para cambiar las imagenes de una pagina creada con angular.

Estoy intentandolo infructuosamente con:

```
this.src=origen+res[res.length-1];
this.setAttribute("ng-src",origen+res[res.length-1])
```

Pero al no actuar sobre el DOM "real" sino uno ya procesado por angular no actualiza la imagen.
¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo una vez la web ya ha sido cargada y desde un JS externo, como son los snippets o las extensiones?

Vaya por delante que no solo conozco angular superficialmente, gracias

Comment: Si vas a cambiar algo de una página ya generada, olvida con qué está hecha: cambia src y no ng-src (Que no es un atributo de Angular, por otro lado... ¿AngularJS, quizá?)

Comment: Es la primera version de angular (creo). He probado con ambas (src y ng-src), y se cambia en el codigo que veo en el inspector, pero no se refresca la imagen por la correcta, imagino que porque no estoy actuando sobre el DOM "original", el de la plantilla de angular, sino en el DOM generado a partir de esta

Comment: No funciona exactamente así, el cambio debería funcionar porque el navegador no sabe interpretar más que el DOM propio, la plantilla es eso: una plantilla para generar el documento final

Comment: Creo que te equivocas, eso seria asi si fuera tecnologia servidor, como php, que el browser recibe el html ya montado, pero si ves el codigo fuente (via boton derecho, view source), lo que yo veo es un` <main>` vacio   porque se genera en tiempo real con JS.  
De hecho no funciona, si que lo hace sobre las imagenes fuera del `<main ng-view>`pero lo que esta dentro es gestionado por angular y no funciona